# Почему кнопки сползают? CSS, PHP

Tags: php, html, css

*На странице вывод парсера выводится 3 раза (~значит выполняется функция из* functions.php *и код в* parser.php(логика)). *Основная причина этого вопроса это то, что кнопки съезжают вниз (не на границу 2х выводов).
При нажатии кнопки - выводится запрос (а), потом кнопки, потом (а), потом хабр.
Думаю, что в коде какая-то небольшая ошибка, и я ее могу быстро найти, но немного устал и нужно сконцентрироваться (а для этого нужно немного отдохнуть и посмотреть, на что-то другое кроме кода). **Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить код, что бы кнопки оставались на месте, а вывод выводился вместо прежнего вывода 1 раз.**
К вопросу добавлю скрины и сам код в текстовом виде.*

---

[image: code]

---

```
if(isset( $_POST['hubrahubr'])){//Если кнопка нажата
                parse_buttons('http://habrahabr.ru', 'div.post');
```

---

```
$html = file_get_html($site);
  $element='empty';
  foreach($html->find($target) as $element){
    echo "<div class='print1'>".$element."</div></div><br>";
  }
```

---

```
<form method="POST">
      <input type="submit" name="hubrahubr" value="Хабр" />
```

---

UPD: [image: UPD_CODE]

---

Исправил код - **ответ на вопрос в скрине UPD**! Все работает!

Comment: Исправил - вывод 2 раза, кнопки сползают в место между выводами.
Почему в диве main выводится форма для запроса и print1 и кнопки?

Comment: Пожалуйста, приводите код **только** в виде текста. Код в виде картинки подразумевает что вы ждете от других участников что они перепечатают его с картинки ради того, чтобы вам помочь.

Comment: @PashaPash, исправил!